# Code Coverage Source Annotation with EclEmma

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, code-coverage, eclemma

I installed EclEmma for its source annotation abilities relating to code coverage, how it highlights code with various colors based on whether or not that code is hit during execution. I intend to use this information for debugging purposes. The default install adds a "launch with coverage" button, which is what I want. This works perfectly for the entry point into the program; that entire source file gets beautiful coverage information smeared all over it. Unfortunately none of the other project files get the same treatment.

When I go over to the new coverage tab I see my source folder structure and all of my source files are listed along with coverage percentages. This is nice, but I would really like it to add the coverage annotations to my other source files so that I can review code coverage line by line in the rest of my project. Presently even clicking on them in the coverage tab with the percentage sitting directly to the right opens the plain unannotated source file (well, unannotated besides Eclipse's normal annotations for Java code). How can I get EclEmma to add source code coverage information to all of my source files, not just the one containing the point of entry to the program?

I suspect that there is a simple fix that I am missing, but the best I can get from the relevant [documentation](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/annotations.html) is how to change the color of the annotations.

For reference I am using Eclipse 4.2.1 for Java development. My EclEmma installation is the one from the Eclipse Marketplace.

Thank you for your time,

-- Techrocket9

Comment: EclEmma is a good tool.  Are you writing unit tests?  My procedure is to write unit tests, run them _all_, (or, all the ones for a section of code under development) then look to see where additional code coverage might be useful.  (A true TDD purist would want you to write the UTs first, but this is the catch-up later technique.

Comment: No, I am not using unit tests on this project. That said, unit testing is something I plan to look into if the codebase grows much larger. Right now I just want to get code coverage source annotation working to help me trace obscure bugs with multithreaded code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unknown reasons the issue seems to have resolved itself. I can only conclude that the EclEmma does not require alteration to display source annotations for other files, and that a bug in my particular Eclipse install triggered the issue and that the bug was fixed in an Eclipse or EclEmma update.